# Error can not be handled properly and crashes my app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

So I am using a express-async-handler for handling async functions and it should automatically add next() after an error is throw, but it looks for some reason it does not.

Here is my function for example:

```js
const getCourse = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const courseId = req.params.id;

  if (courseId.length !== 24) {
    throw new Error("Invalid course Id.");
  }

  const course = await Course.findById(courseId);

  if (!course) {
    return res.status(404).json({
      error: "Course not found.",
    });
  }

  res.status(200).json(course);
});
```

and if any error gets throw i get this output:

```
Listening on port 1337
/home/legasi/moonWebAcademy/backend/src/controllers/course-controller.js:51
        throw new Error("Invalid course Id."); // or throw new InvalidIdFormatError("Invalid course Id.");
              ^

Error: Invalid course Id.
```

and the app crashes after the error is throw. I have a error handler middleware in my app.js but the error never gets to it:

```js
app.use(courseRoute);

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.log("1");
  res.status(err.status || 500).json({ error: err.message });
});
```

here is the how i register it in router:

```
router.route("/api/courses/:id")
  .put(courseUpdateValidationRules, (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    updateCourse(req, res);
  })
  .delete((req, res) => {
    deleteCourse(req, res); 
  })
  .get((req,res) => {
    getCourse(req,res)
});
```

I really do not know what to do anymore and how to fix this. Thanks!

Comment: `asyncHandler()` wraps your code in its own `(req, res, next) => {...}` function. By not passing `next` to it, it cannot handle any uncaught errors. So you either want `.get((req, res, next) => { getCourse(req, res, next) })` or much more simply `.get(getCourse)`

Comment: Thank you so much man this worked! I dying to fix this! express-async-handler lacks some of the docs. Ty!